# Xcode 6 app won't stop launching in zoom mode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios-universal-app, size-classes

I have an app that was created in a previous version of Xcode.  It used to not be universal so it launched in 1x/2x mode on an iPad.

Now we want it to run with universal storyboards and size classes.  We have converted the storyboards to size classes and changed the project setting to "Universal".  We have set up the constraints and it runs fine on iPhone 6 and 5 flavors.  But when we launch on an iPad is launches in 2x Mode automatically.

I can not figure out what is going on.

Can not find anything here or on the googles that speaks to this issue.  Everyone seems to have success with the steps I enumerated.  One post I found here talks about using a launch file, but I changed our launch file to our main storyboard and it still launches in 2x mode.

Appreciate the help.  Let me know if there is any screen shots or more info that would help make things clearer.

**EDIT**

Adding screen shots for the first comment below.

[image]

[image]

**Edit #2**

I wonder if it has something to do with the xibs in the storyboard not updating in the newer Xcode.  This project was started long ago and the days before storyboards. All I know is that with the latest update of the beta Xcode it just magically works.  So strange.

Comment: Did you add Default.png for iPad? Or started using a launch screen xib?

Comment: Well I'm confused by what you mean.  We are not using a Default.png for any size and when I use our main Storyboard as a launch file it doesn't make a difference. Adding screen shots to question for clarity.

Comment: Is the entire app in what you call "zoom" mode? Or just the launch screen?

Comment: It's the entire app. Good question.

Comment: Would sharing your project be possible so I can run it on simulators on a different machine?

Comment: Sadly no.  Perhaps it's so messed up I'll have to bumble through alone.  Thanks for being willing though.

Comment: Okay, no problem. I'm having trouble understanding what you mean by zoom mode. Did everything inside your root `UIWindow` grow by 2x in both dimensions? So you can only see 1/4 of what you would normally see?

Comment: No.  Remember how in iOS < 7 you could run an iPhone app on an iPad without changing anything about the project.  The only caveat was that it ran in a mode where it was either 1x (normal iPhone size) or 2x mode where it was pixel doubled so that it "looked" like it was iPad sized.  It has the little "2x"and "1x" circular button in the bottom right.  My impression from reading the docs is that all it takes to get rid of this and have it run iPad size is to make it universal and use size classes.

Answer (score 0):

Problems solved when the latest Xcode Beta came out.  Possibly something weird with the xibs since this is an old/converted project that stated before storyboards.